# vue-cli3 syntax error in ie11 in prodcution

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3

### babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      "@vue/app",
      {
        useBuiltIns: "entry",
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

### main.js

```
import '@babel/polyfill'
```

### package.json

```
"browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 10"
  ],
```

above's config is my `vue-cli3` project, the `class` was not be polyfill, why?
[image]

### thirdpart lib

```
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "jsonp": "^0.2.1",
    "swiper": "^4.4.6",
    "video.js": "^7.4.1",
    "videojs": "^1.0.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.22",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
```

Comment: What version of vue-cli are you using?

Comment: @Phil vue -V  ->
v3.3.0.

Comment: Try upgrading. There's a bunch of bugs fixed relating to IE11

Answer (score 1):

I solved it myself. It turned out to be a problem with swiper.js.
but, I have add config to vue.config.js, it's not works.

```
transpileDependencies: [
    'swiper'
],
```

is a bug?